# Webpage min-height on different resolutions

Tags: html, css

I got into little problem. I want to create my website to be atlest full height of user's vertical resolution. This is my html:

```
<div id="head"></div>
<div id="body"></div>
<div id="legs"></div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#head {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: gold;
}
#body {
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px; /* This needs to be defined as remaining height */
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#legs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: gold;
}
```

And here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QgfJ3/embedded/result/ . As you can see `#head` is 65px high and `#legs` is 20px high. The problem is that I want to expand `#body`'s high depending on user's resolution. For example if user has 800x600, it means that it used `#head`'s 65px and `#legs`'s 20px, that makes 85px total. There is still 715px remaining, so how to set this height to `#body`?

Comment: Hehe `#legs`, nice synonym for footer :D

Comment: why dont you try setting the height interms of percentages(%).depending on the ratio you want to give it for `#head`, `#legs` and `#body`

Comment: I use also `left-hand` and `right-hand` for banner on left and right side of website. :D

Comment: @dreamweiver because  `#head` and  `#legs` needs to be set in pixels. It can't change how it wants.

Comment: @Kyrbi hahaha nice one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use javascript or calc (http://caniuse.com/calc)

jQuery method:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('#body').height($(window).height() - $('#head').height() - $('#legs').height());
});
```

Javascript (not sure if works with IE):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    document.querySelector('#body').style.height = window.innerHeight - 85 + 'px';
}, false);
```

calc:

```
#body {
    height: calc(100% - 85px);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it too heavy to use jQuery for just a little thing? I mean user will have to load whole jQuery for just one thing. Wouldn't be simple Javascript better choice?

Comment: There you go, it is a very simple solution and does not propably cover all browsers but I think you get the idea!